# Error when using Makefile..sed

Tags: make, gnu-make

An app is trying to configure with

```
sudo make configure
(cd /opt/ioapi-3.2/ioapi   ;  sed -e 's|IOAPI_BASE|/opt/ioapi-3.2|' -e 's|LIBINSTALL||' -e 's|BININSTALL||' -e 's|IOAPI_DEFS||' -e 's|NCFLIBS|-L/opt/netcdf/lib -lnetcdff -L/opt/netcdf/lib -lnetcdf|' -e 's|MAKEINCLUDE|include /opt/ioapi-3.2/ioapi/Makeinclude|' -e 's|PVMINCLUDE|include  |' < Makefile..sed > Makefile )
/bin/sh: Makefile..sed: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:211: configure] Error 1
```

I don't understand what the last part of the command is supposed to do and therefore why it's generating the error.

The output from `make -n configure` is:

```
(cd /home/centos/ioapi-3.2/ioapi   ;  sed -e 's|IOAPI_BASE|/home/centos/ioapi-3.2|' -e 's|LIBINSTALL||' -e 's|BININSTALL||' -e 's|IOAPI_DEFS||' -e 's|NCFLIBS|-lnetcdff -lnetcdf|' -e 's|MAKEINCLUDE|include /home/centos/ioapi-3.2/ioapi/Makeinclude|' -e 's|PVMINCLUDE|include  |' < Makefile..sed > Makefile )
(cd /home/centos/ioapi-3.2/m3tools ;  sed -e 's|IOAPI_BASE|/home/centos/ioapi-3.2|' -e 's|LIBINSTALL||' -e 's|BININSTALL||' -e 's|IOAPI_DEFS||' -e 's|NCFLIBS|-lnetcdff -lnetcdf|' -e 's|MAKEINCLUDE|include /home/centos/ioapi-3.2/ioapi/Makeinclude|' -e 's|PVMINCLUDE|include  |' < Makefile..sed > Makefile )
```

Comment: `< Makefile..sed` attempts to redirect input from a file named `Makefile..sed` - if the file does not exits, you will get the observed error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: The double dot in `Makefile..sed` smells like something is missing, like `Makefile.foo.sed`. What does `ls -l Makefile.*.sed` have to offer? This could give a hint what causes the problem.

Comment: Did you follow the [build instructions](https://cjcoats.github.io/ioapi/AVAIL.html#build)? Especially point 3 talks about several customization that you are expected to make.

Comment: I was following the instructions in the CMAQ user guide. They're similar and I did customize Makefile, ioapi/Makefile, and m3tools/Makefile along with Makeinclude.

Comment: I tried to compile as user rather than as root just to check it out but it was the same problem. There's only one Makefile and it's still unclear why it's seeking Makefile..sed,

Comment: Can you share the output of the command  `make -n configure`

Comment: Sorry that I didn't see your comment. The output is posted. I contacted the developer and he suggested to build component by component rather than from the top tree. When compiling from the top tree, it should read Makefile.sed rather than Makefile..sed but I'm still not sure why the extra period is being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `Makefile.template` file of the `ioapic-3.2` project [on GitHub](https://github.com/cjcoats/ioapi-3.2/blob/master/Makefile.template), it is clear that the `sed` command that you are seeing is the result of `make` using the `SEDCMD` variable:

```
SEDCMD = \
-e 's|IOAPI_BASE|$(BASEDIR)|' \
-e 's|LIBINSTALL|$(LIBINST)|' \
-e 's|BININSTALL|$(BININST)|' \
-e 's|IOAPI_DEFS|$(IOAPIDEFS)|' \
-e 's|NCFLIBS|$(NCFLIBS)|' \
-e 's|MAKEINCLUDE|include $(IODIR)/Makeinclude|' \
-e 's|PVMINCLUDE|include  $(PVMINCL)|'
```

like so:

```
configure: ${IODIR}/Makefile ${TOOLDIR}/Makefile
    (cd $(IODIR)   ;  sed $(SEDCMD) < Makefile.$(CPLMODE).sed > Makefile )
    (cd $(TOOLDIR) ;  sed $(SEDCMD) < Makefile.$(CPLMODE).sed > Makefile )
```

As you can see, it tries to read a file called `Makefile.$(CPLMODE).sed`. The `CPLMODE` variable is mentioned several times *in comments* in the Makefile, but never set to a default value.

It seems that valid values for this variable is `nocpl`, `cpl`, or `pncf`.  The `README.txt` file in the repository says to customize the Makefile, which I must assume includes making a copy of `Makefile.template` called `Makefile` in the top-level directory of the project and then modifying this.

You just haven't made all the necessary modifications to it yet it seems.